# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a code to convert the cost into EURO according to the currency scenario in SQL Server. However I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

Help me please.

```sql
SELECT 
    WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].PartNumber,
    WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].COST,
    CASE 
       WHEN WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].CURRENCY = 'GBP' 
          THEN (WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].COST * 1.17)
       WHEN WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].CURRENCY = 'USD' 
          THEN (WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].COST * 0.87)
       WHEN WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].CURRENCY = 'EUR' 
          THEN (WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].COST * 1)
       ELSE ('NO CURRENCY AVAILABLE') 
    END AS CIFCOST
FROM
    ['Parts Detail$']
```

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that returns a single, atomic value - and **all** paths and all possible values being returned **must be** the same datatype - this is **NOT** the case here! In three cases, you return a `FLOAT` - but in the `ELSE` clause, you return a string. SQL Server will pick the datatype with the highest datatype precedence - here `FLOAT` - and will try to convert all other return values to that type - hence the error message ..

Answer (score 0):

Your `ELSE` clause may be causing the problem.  Just return `NULL`:

```
       ELSE NULL END AS CIFCOST
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `ELSE ('NO CURRENCY AVAILABLE')`

```
SELECT WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].PartNumber,
       WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].COST,
       CASE 
            WHEN WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].CURRENCY = 'GBP' THEN (WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].COST*1.17)
            WHEN WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].CURRENCY= 'USD' THEN (WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].COST*0.87)
            WHEN WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].CURRENCY='EUR' THEN (WORK.dbo.['Parts Detail$'].COST*1)
            ELSE null END AS CIFCOST
FROM ['Parts Detail$']
```

you can't contain stirng value in float  type